# In C++, what is causing the difference between these two functions?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

So I wrote these two versions of the overloaded assignment operator for an ADT I wrote in class. When I use them in conjunction with my overloaded ostream << operator for that same ADT I see different results. Why? Is it because I deallocated the memory to the other buffer that I am receiving this issue?

```
void Text::operator= (const Text &other) { 
if (this != &other) {
    delete [] buffer;
    bufferSize = other.bufferSize;
    buffer = new char[bufferSize + 1];
    strcpy(buffer, other.buffer);
    }
}

 void Text::operator= (const Text &other) { 
if (this != &other) {
    delete [] buffer;
    bufferSize = other.bufferSize;
    buffer = new char[bufferSize + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
         buffer[i] = other.buffer[i];
     }
}
```

Here is my overloaded ostream <<,

```
ostream & operator << (ostream &output, const Text &outputText) {
output << outputText.buffer;
return output;
}
```

The discrepancy occurs like this:

The first one outputs: `Hey Jude`

The second one outputs: `Hey Jude(random garbage)`

Comment: In this context, how are you setting bufferSize?

Comment: Read about copy-and-swap idiom,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second code snippet does not append a terminating null terminator, hence the garbage (`strcpy()` copies the terminating null). You need to explicitly add the null terminator after the `for` loop:

```
buffer[bufferSize] = 0;
```

Comment: What about memcpy as an alternative that does not need the ending 0?

Comment: Key oversight for me was 'null-terminated' sequence of characters. If I don't copy over the null character, then how is it going to terminate?

Answer (score 2):

Little trick:

```
buffer = new char[bufferSize + 1]();
```

This:

```
strcpy(buffer, other.buffer);
```

also copies the null-terminating character. This:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
     buffer[i] = other.buffer[i];
 }
```

doesn't, because it's at position `bufferSize+1`, which you skip.

I'd probably go with iterating to position `bufferSize+1` instead of value-initializing the array.

Okay, scrap that, I'd go with using a `std::string` instead. That way, you don't have to worry about copying, assignment or destruction.